# Selecting more rows for a distinct with less columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've encountered two contradicting queries, which suggest that a distinct on 2 columns can return more rows than a distinct on 4 columns (which include those 2).

alpha_id and beta_id are NUMBER; delta and gamma are VARCHAR2.

The first query I run returns me the following counts:
`29'252'799` when `THE_LINE = alpha_id, beta_id, delta, gamma`
`111'163'500` when `THE_LINE = alpha_id, beta_id`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ____________ -- (THE_LINE)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT alpha_id,
      beta_id,
      delta,
      gamma
    FROM table_in_question
    WHERE alpha_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND (delta, gamma) IN (('FIRST', 'SECOND'), ('FIRST', 'THIRD'))
  )
);
```

The second query, which should be logically identical, involves creating a table, then selecting from that. These are the counts:
`29'252'799` when `THE_SAME_LINE = alpha_id, beta_id, delta, gamma`
`27'976'202` when `THE_SAME_LINE = alpha_id, beta_id`

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table TABLESPACE flash AS
SELECT DISTINCT alpha_id,
  beta_id,
  delta,
  gamma
FROM table_in_question
WHERE alpha_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND (delta, gamma) IN (('FIRST', 'SECOND'), ('FIRST', 'THIRD'));

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ____________ -- (THE_SAME_LINE)
  FROM tmp_table
);
```

The second query makes sense - It returns more rows if there are more columns selected. The first query, however, returns more rows with **less** columns selected.

Could this have something to do with the partition I've got on `alpha_id`?
Note that the only values in the alpha_id column at the moment are 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Any ideas on why the first query gives such strange results?

Comment: I suppose one cause for this behavior would be different collations.  If the original table was case sensitive (for example) but the database was not case sensitive, then the `distinct` might work differently in the two cases.

Comment: Trying this with UPPER() all around. Taking a while, since... Millions of rows. Great suggestion, ty Gordon.

Comment: No, looks like the case is irrelevant here. Everything is already uppercase.

Comment: You can't specify collations on individual tables in Oracle @Gordon. The minimum would be the session level.

Comment: This seems to be incorrect. Your current queries are logically identical, so it's not clear what you mean by "for all 4". Can you post the query you're running to get the 111m row result? Assuming your result is true; you should be able to formulate a query relatively simply to work out what the additional rows you're getting are. I suspect you've just got a logic problem, which you've removed in attempting to convert this into something obfuscated. If you're unable to post unobfuscated code can you provide a minimal example that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: by "for all 4" I mean for all 4 columns. If I replace those 2 columns (`alpha_id, beta_id`) with all 4 (`alpha_id, beta_id, delta, gamma`)

Comment: I reworked the question. Go ahead and check it over again for more clarity.